# Creating tags for Fall 2014 series

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

We've recently had a slight drop in traffic, and while that in and of itself isn't too worrying for a number of reasons, it does indicate that we should probably at least look at whether there's anything we're not doing right.

If we want to get traffic, the most obvious series to target are those that are currently airing. But at the moment, we don't even have tags for a very large number of currently airing series. Not having a tag means that new users aren't likely to bring their questions to us, unless they happen to be aware of [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) or use something else that doesn't quite fit. So it makes sense to prioritize creating tags for these series.

Of course, the way tags are created on Stack Exchange sites is by users asking questions. We can't create tags if no one is asking a question, and even if we did the tags would be removed if they weren't being used on any questions. So what this really means is that we need people to volunteer to ask a question about these series to get the tags into the system.

Given that Fall 2014 season is just beginning, now seems like a good time to do this. The purpose of this post is to keep track of what series are airing this season, what tags already exist, and which series still need tags, and to coordinate efforts to create these.

If you're willing to contribute by asking a (good) question about one of these series, feel free to leave a comment under the answer. Once you do (preferably as soon as possible), edit the relevant line on the answer to point to the tag page. The hope is that by doing this, we can get to something like 50% coverage of all airing anime, which would mean most popular things are covered.

Of course, this is completely optional, but if you do notice a series that you're watching is listed as *no tag*, at least consider whether you can come up with a good question about it.

Comment: The problem I find with new shows is that I usually wait until the show is concluded to find out if the answer is explained. And then you don't need the prompt questions anymore

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko While that precludes some types of story questions, there are other questions you can ask which are not directly about the story and not likely to be answered in the show itself.

Comment: Do we know if passing visitors actually become less likely to ask something if they don't find an existing tag?

Comment: @user1306322 It would be very hard for us to get statistics on this, but it seems inevitable since the system offers literally no helpful guidance in this case. I do know that during one of the podcasts, someone from Stack Exchange mentioned that they tracked traffic on a similar site (probably Arqade) and noticed that it was quite common common for users to try to ask a question, but leave after realizing the tag didn't exist, and that this seemed to adversely affect most of the sites which weren't focused on technology or science. It's hard to see how the story would be different here.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a list of all TV anime (ignoring shorts) airing in Fall 2014 as per [Anichart](http://anichart.net/fall). Each one is listed together with any relevant tags. They're sorted by start date. Shows from last season are included, but long-running shows (among which we have fairly good coverage) are not.

- **Shirogane no Ishi: Argevollen**  *no tag*
- **Pretty Guardian Sailor Moon: Crystal** [sailor-moon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sailor-moon)
- **PuriPara** *no tag*
- **Sword Art Online 2** [sword-art-online](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sword-art-online)
- **Akame ga Kill!** [akame-ga-kill](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akame-ga-kill)
- **Francesca** *no tag*
- **Yama no Susume Second Season** *no tag*
- **TERRA FORMARS** [terra-formars](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terra-formars)
- **Tribe Cool Crew** *no tag*
- **Aikatsu 3** *no tag*
- **Denki-Gai no Honya-san** [denkigai-no-honya-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denkigai-no-honya-san)
- **Amagi Brilliant Park** [amagi-brilliant-park](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amagi-brilliant-park)
- **Danna ga Nani wo Itteru ka Wakaranai Ken** [danna-wakaranai-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danna-wakaranai-ken)
- **Gundam: G no Reconguista** [gundam](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam)
- **Donten ni Warau** *no tag*
- **Garo: Honoo no Kokuin** [garo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garo)
- **Log Horizon 2nd Series** [log-horizon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log-horizon)
- **Madan no Ou to Vanadis**  *no tag*
- **Magic Kaito 1412** [kaito-kid](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaito-kid)
- **Selector Spread WIXOSS** [wixoss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wixoss)
- **Ushinawareta Mirai wo Motomete** [waremete](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waremete)
- **Cross Ange: Tenshi to Ryuu no Rondo**  [cross-ange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-ange)
- **Fate/stay night: Unlimited Blade Works** [fate-stay-night](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-stay-night)
- **Grisaia no Kajitsu** [le-fruit-de-la-grisaia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/le-fruit-de-la-grisaia)
- **Ookami Shoujo to Kuro Ouji** *no tag*
- **Sora no Method** [sora-no-method](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sora-no-method)
- **The Seven Deadly Sins** [nanatsu-no-taizai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanatsu-no-taizai)
- **World Trigger** [world-trigger](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-trigger)
- **Gugure! Kokkuri-san** [gugure-kokkuri-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gugure-kokkuri-san)
- **Kaitou Joker** *no tag*
- **Orenchi no Furo Jijou** *no tag*
- **Rage of Bahamut Genesis** [shingeki-no-bahamut](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shingeki-no-bahamut)
- **Akatsuki no Yona** [akatsuki-no-yona](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akatsuki-no-yona)
- **Inou-Battle wa Nichijou-kei no Naka de** [inou-battle](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/inou-battle)
- **Yowamushi Pedal: Grande Road** [yowamushi-pedal](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yowamushi-pedal)
- **Gundam Build Fighters Try** [gundam](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam) [gundam-build-fighters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam-build-fighters)
- **Trinity Seven: 7-nin no Mahoutsukai** [trinity-seven](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trinity-seven)
- **Chaika -The Coffin Princess- Avenging Battle** [hitsugi-no-chaika](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitsugi-no-chaika)
- **Daitoshokan no Hitsujikai** *no tag*
- **Parasyte** [parasyte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parasyte)
- **SHIROBAKO** [shirobako](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shirobako)
- **Ore, Twintails ni Narimasu.** *no tag*
- **Psycho-Pass 2** [psycho-pass](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psycho-pass)
- **Your Lie in April** [shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso)
- **Ronia the Robber's Daughter** [ronia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronia)
- **Girlfriend (Kari)** *no tag*
- **Yuki Yuna wa Yusha de Aru** [yuki-yuna-is-a-hero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuki-yuna-is-a-hero)
- **Mushishi Zoku Shou 2** [mushishi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushishi)
- **Karen Senki** [karen-senki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karen-senki)

We currently have **35/50** tags.

Comment: These are only animes? Or include LN's, Novels and Manga?

Comment: @Braiam Just anime. Manga, LNs, etc are more varied in terms of scheduling and typically maintain fanbases for longer, but for anime we really only have a 3-month window where interest is peaked for the average show, so it's important to get them tagged during that period whenever possible.