# Winter 2015 series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

We had a pretty successful meta post last season with the intent of getting as many series tagged as possible: [Creating tags for Fall 2014 series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/creating-tags-for-fall-2014-series). More than half the series there ended up being tagged, which is ultimately a good thing and reduces the need for workarounds like [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag). So I figured we might as well continue doing it as long as it's working, and Winter season is about to start, so this is the right time to post this.

This season has more sequels and fewer new series, so we're starting off with more series tagged, but we should still aim to get as many of the remaining ones tagged as possible.

**What series are airing in Winter 2015, and which have tags?**

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [Anichart](http://anichart.net/winter) with English titles and ordering the series by air date, with carry-overs listed first (alphabetically), and ignoring short anime (but at this point we're still not 100% sure which ones will be shorts). This answer is CW, so feel free to modify it as needed.

- **Akatsuki no Yona** [akatsuki-no-yona](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akatsuki-no-yona)
- **CROSS ANGE: Rondo of Angel and Dragon** [cross-ange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-ange)
- **Garo: Honoo no Kokuin** [garo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garo)
- **Log Horizon 2** [log-horizon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/log-horizon)
- **Magic Kaito 1412** [kaito-kid](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kaito-kid)
- **Parasyte -the maxim-** [parasyte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parasyte)
- **Ronia the Robber's Daughter**  [ronia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronia)
- **Shirobako** [shirobako](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shirobako)
- **The Seven Deadly Sins** [nanatsu-no-taizai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanatsu-no-taizai)
- **World Trigger** [world-trigger](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-trigger)
- **Your lie in April** [shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shigatsu-wa-kimi-no-uso)
- **Yowamushi Pedal: Grande Road** [yowamushi-pedal](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yowamushi-pedal)
- **Tantei Opera Milky Holmes TD** *no tag* (use `tantei-opera-milky-holmes`)

---

- **Absolute Duo** [absolute-duo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absolute-duo)
- **Yuri Kuma Arashi** [yuri-kuma-arashi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuri-kuma-arashi)
- **Kamisama Kiss◎** [kamisama-kiss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kamisama-kiss)
- **Binan Koukou Chikyuu Bouei-bu Love!** [boueibu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boueibu)
- **Kantai Collection: Kan Colle** [kantai-collection](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kantai-collection)
- **The Testament of Sister New Devil** *no tag* (use `shinmai-maou-no-testament`)
- **Tokyo Ghoul √A** [tokyo-ghoul](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokyo-ghoul)
- **Saekano: How to Raise a Boring Girlfriend** [saekano](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saekano)
- **Koufuku Graffiti** [koufuku-graffiti](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koufuku-graffiti)
- **Juuou Mujin no Fafnir** *no tag*
- **Soukyuu no Fafner: Dead Aggressor - Exodus** *no tag* (use `soukyuu-no-fafner`)
- **THE iDOLM@STER: Cinderella Girls** [the-idolmaster](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-idolmaster)
- **JoJo's Bizarre Adventure Part 3: Stardust Crusaders 2** [jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jojo-no-kimyouna-bouken)
- **Assassination Classroom** [assassination-classroom](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassination-classroom)
- **Death Parade** [death-billiards](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-billiards) [death-parade](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-parade)
- **Shounen Hollywood: Holly Stage for 50** *no tag*
- **Durarara!!x2 Shou** [durarara](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/durarara)
- **Aldnoah.Zero 2** [aldnoah-zero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aldnoah-zero)
- **Dog Days''** [dog-days](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog-days)
- **Rolling☆Girls** *no tag*
- **Kuroko's Basketball 3** [kuroko-no-basket](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuroko-no-basket)
- **Yoru no Yatterman** *no tag*
- **Junketsu no Maria** [junketsu-no-maria](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/junketsu-no-maria)
- **Seiken Tsukai no World Break** [world-break](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-break)
- **Sengoku Musou** *no tag*
- **Isuca** *no tag*
- **Go! Princess Precure** [pretty-cure](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pretty-cure)

We currently have **31/40** tags.

Comment: I've added some suggested tag names for series that don't have tags and for which the choice of tag name is not necessarily obvious. Not sure what we should use for Seiken Tsukai no World Break, though - `seiken-tsukai-no-world-break` is too long.

Comment: I would suggest changing death-billiards into death-parade as the series sounds like it will be more than just billiards and also it is larger than a single OVA

Comment: @senshin: There are some choices such as `warubure` (the name of the production committee), `world-break` or `seiken-world-break`.