# Proposal: bounties for tags

Tags: discussion, tags, bounty

In the spirit of [Winter 2015 series tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/1908), I would like to promote the creation of tags for older series. As such, I think I want to start disbursing bounties to users that create tags for older series.

I have included a proposal below for doing this on a rolling season-by-season basis (starting with shows from summer 2011 [chosen arbitrarily - but this is obviously going to be more successful if we stick to the relatively recent past] that don't have tags), and would like some of you folks to take a look at it and see if it's reasonable - does it achieve the goal of getting more tags in the system without encouraging perverse behavior? Are there any grey areas I need to clarify? Are there any other changes I should make?

This proposal doesn't strictly require buy-in from other users, I guess, but I hope that this sounds like a good idea to the rest of the community. If any other high-rep users want to join in and help me award some bounties, that would be nifty, too.

If this works out, I imagine we can do something like one season a month or so, until we've hit all the seasons from Fall 2012 (i.e. when this site launched) back to Winter 2005 or so (this would take about three years, granted; I'm taking a long view of things here), perhaps pausing occasionally to focus on some other subset of anime, e.g. movies from a few-year period, or a particular studio's works, or a mega-franchise like Gundam, or whatnot.

There is precedent for this sort of thing on other Stack Exchange sites, though I can't for the life of me remember which ones. I think Code Golf might've been one of them?

---

(Title: Bounties for tags, summer 2011 edition)

### How it's going to work

If you create a tag for one of the series on the list of approved series below (by asking a question with that tag), during the month of February 2015,<sup>4</sup> I will award you a 50-reputation bounty, subject to certain conditions on you:

- You must have posted at least one answer on the site with a score of at least 1.<sup>1</sup>
- You must have less than 10,000 reputation on February 1, 2015.<sup>2</sup>

And also subject to certain conditions on the question you ask with the new tag:

- The question must have received a net score of at least 3 by February 28 or 7 days after it was posted - whichever is later.<sup>3</sup>
- The question must not be closed or deleted.

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) and mention that you need somebody with more reputation to create the tag, and somebody will surely take care of that for you. I will give you (rather than the high-rep user who physically creates the tag) credit for creating the tag.

In the interest of getting broader participation, I will award at most 3 bounties (so, 150 reputation) to any given user.

If someone creates a tag but is disqualified from receiving a bounty for any of the reasons above, the bounty may still be awarded to the next user who asked a question in that tag, unless *they* are disqualified for some reason, in which case I'll go on to the *next* user, and so forth. So, if somebody "beats you to the punch", but you think their question is unlikely to get a high enough score by the deadline, and you think you have a better question, go ahead and post it! Who knows - you could well win the bounty.

These rules are subject to revision by me at any time and for any reason.<sup>6</sup>

### Approved series<sup>5</sup>

- [Battle Spirits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=battle-spirits)
- [Blade](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=blade)
- [Dantalian no Shoka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=dantalian-no-shoka)
- [Ganbare!! Nattou-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ganbare-nattou-san)
- [Ikoku Meiro no Croisee](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ikoku-meiro-no-croisee)
- [Itsuka Tenma no Kuro Usagi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=itsuka-tenma-kuro-usagi)
- [Kaitou Tenshi Twin Angel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kaitou-tenshi-twin-angel)
- [Kakko Kawaii Sengen!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kakko-kawaii-sengen)
- [Kamisama no Memochou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kamisama-no-memochou)
- [Manyuu Hikenchou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=manyuu-hikenchou)
- [Monster Hunter](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=monster-hunter)
- [Morita-san wa Mukuchi.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=morita-san-wa-mukuchi)
- [No.6](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=no-6)
- [Nurarihyon no Mago](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nurarihyon-no-mago)
- [Nyanpire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nyanpire)
- [R-15](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=r-15)
- [Sacred Seven](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sacred-seven)
- [Usagi Drop](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=usagi-drop)
- [Uta no Prince-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=uta-no-prince-sama)

### Details

<sup>1</sup> Bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions, so it's impossible for me to award a bounty unless you've posted an answer somewhere. I ask for a score of 1 or more because I don't want to encourage people posting rubbish as an expedient for earning the bounty.

<sup>2</sup> I also envision this as a redistributive mechanism; if you have at least 10,000 reputation, you will still have access to moderator tools after the site graduates, and so you aren't really in need of any rep redistribution.

<sup>3</sup> The minimum score requirement is there because, again, I don't want to encourage people spamming terrible questions to earn bounties.

<sup>4</sup> In any timezone, so from 12:00 UTC on Jan 31 to 12:00 UTC on Mar 1.

<sup>5</sup> This list is derived from [AniChart's list of Summer 2011 shows](http://anichart.net/archive/summer-11). Series that already have tags are, of course, excluded.

<sup>6</sup> This clause will probably only need to be in effect for the first iteration of this thing, to combat any degenerate behavior that ensues as a result of something I haven't foreseen. Once this is fully hashed out, we can drop this clause.

Comment: does that mean user who create tag of 2011 will only get the bounty not for earlier/older than 2011

Comment: @mirroroftruth That's the idea. I think it's useful to keep things focused, rather than just saying "you make tags, I give rep".