# February 2015 bounties for tags: summer 2011 shows

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

Absent any opposition to [my proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/proposal-bounties-for-tags), I hereby announce the first iteration of the bounties-for-tags program.

### How it's going to work

If you create a tag for a **summer 2011** show (that's on the list of approved series below) by asking a question with that tag, I will award you a **50-reputation bounty** (Which will be **matched** by Madara), provided that:

- The question is posted during the month of **February 2015**.
- The question receives a net score of at least **+3** by March 7, 2015, and isn't closed or deleted. (we want good questions, not bad ones)
- You have posted at least one answer on the site with a score of at least 0. (bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions)
- You have less than 10,000 reputation at the time of this posting. (this excludes Krazer / Jon Lin / Logan / Eric / Madara / kuwaly: no sense in making the rich richer)

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 rep), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) and mention that you need somebody with more reputation to create the tag, and somebody will surely take care of that for you. I will give you (rather than the higher-rep user who physically creates the tag) credit for creating the tag.

In the interest of getting broader participation, I will award at most 4 bounties (so, 200 reputation) to any one user.

If someone creates a tag but is disqualified from receiving a bounty for any of the reasons above, the bounty may still be awarded to the next user who asked a question in that tag, unless they are disqualified for some reason, in which case I'll go on to the next user, and so forth. So, if somebody "beats you to the punch", but they already have >10k rep, or you think their question is unlikely to get a high enough score by the deadline, go ahead and post your question! Who knows - you could well win the bounty.

These rules are subject to revision by me at any time and for any reason. (But I probably won't unless I seriously overlooked something important.)

### Approved series from summer 2011

- [Battle Spirits](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=battle-spirits)
- [Blade](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=blade)
- [Dantalian no Shoka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=dantalian-no-shoka)
- [Ganbare!! Nattou-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ganbare-nattou-san)
- [Ikoku Meiro no Croisee](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ikoku-meiro-no-croisee)
- [Itsuka Tenma no Kuro Usagi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=itsuka-tenma-kuro-usagi)
- [Kaitou Tenshi Twin Angel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kaitou-tenshi-twin-angel)
- [Kakko Kawaii Sengen!](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kakko-kawaii-sengen)
- [Kamisama no Memochou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kamisama-no-memochou)
- [Manyuu Hikenchou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=manyuu-hikenchou)
- [Monster Hunter](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=monster-hunter)
- [Morita-san wa Mukuchi.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=morita-san-wa-mukuchi)
- [No.6](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=no-6)
- [Nurarihyon no Mago](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nurarihyon-no-mago)
- [Nyanpire](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nyanpire)
- [R-15](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=r-15)
- [Sacred Seven](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sacred-seven)
- [Usagi Drop](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=usagi-drop)
- [Uta no Prince-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=uta-no-prince-sama)

Comment: I will match any bounty given by senshin with the same amount.

Comment: Should created Tag contain info or just create a tag no need to add info because nobody will bother themselves to read info of tag.

Comment: @mirroroftruth You don't need to worry about adding info in the tag wiki (though you can, if you want to). Like you say, people don't read those very often. Also, I go through the tag wikis once every few months and fill in any blank tag wikis, so they'll get taken care of eventually. The main goal here is to ensure that the tags simply exist in the system, so that _new_ users who may have a question in that tag actually have the tag show up for them.

Comment: Why summer 2011?

Comment: @3.1415926535897932384626433832 Arbitrary choice, basically - I picked a season that was before this site was founded, but still recent enough that a fair number of users are likely to have watched anime during that season.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha When you get a chance, you might like to remove [meta-tag:featured] from this, now that February is over.

Answer (score 2):

The February version of the bounties-for-tags program is now over. The following tags were created:

- [ikoku-meiro-no-croisee](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ikoku-meiro-no-croisee) - [What do we know about Yune's father?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19105/)
- [nurarihyon-no-mago](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nurarihyon-no-mago) - [Can someone identify this girl in Nurarihyon no Mago?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19052/)
- [usagi-drop](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usagi-drop) - [Is the identity of Rin's father confirmed?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19397/)

I am changing the rules so that questions only need to have a score of **1** (rather than 3) in order to win a bounty - it occurred to me that at the current size of the site, many of the niche shows for which we're trying to get tags simply might not have enough eyes to earn more upvotes, and that's honestly fine. As long as *somebody* think the question's good enough for an upvote, that's good enough for me. Since all of the tag-creating questions have a score of at least 1 right now, I'm going to award the bounties shortly rather than waiting for March 7.

(Note to Madara - of course, it's at your discretion whether to match the bounties according to the original rules or according to the changed rules, or according to whatever rules you want, really.)

This means that the following users win bounties from me:

- [Tsugumori-704](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/11206/tsugumori-704) wins 100 reputation, for creating [nurarihyon-no-mago](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nurarihyon-no-mago) and [usagi-drop](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usagi-drop).
- [Torisuda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/7579/torisuda) wins 50 reputation, for creating [ikoku-meiro-no-croisee](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ikoku-meiro-no-croisee)

[Congratulations!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyTM1.jpg) I'll leave the bounties up for about a day, and then award them to you.

Details about the [**March 2015** bounties-for-tags program](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2281/1908) are now available. The theme: Studio Ghibli anime.