# March 2015 bounties for tags: Studio Ghibli anime

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

### The rules

If you create a tag for a **Studio Ghibli** anime (see the list below) by asking a question with that tag, I will award you a **50-reputation bounty**, provided that:

- The question is posted during the month of **March 2015**.
- The question receives a net score of at least **+1** by April 7, 2015, and isn't closed or deleted. (We want good questions, not bad ones.) <sub>*Note: The February contest initially required a score of +3; this has been changed to +1*</sub>
- You have posted at least one answer on the site with a score of at least 0. (Bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions.)
- You have less than 10,000 reputation at the time of this posting. (This excludes Krazer / Jon Lin / Logan / Eric / Madara / kuwaly: no sense in making the rich richer.)

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 rep), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) and mention that you need somebody with more reputation to create the tag, and somebody will surely take care of that for you. I will give you (rather than the higher-rep user who physically creates the tag) credit for creating the tag.

There is no limit on the number of bounties you can win (other than that you obviously can't win more bounties than there are tags to be made). <sub>*Note: This is a change from Feb 2015*</sub>

If someone creates a tag but is disqualified from receiving a bounty for any of the reasons above, the bounty may still be awarded to the next user who asked a question in that tag, unless they are disqualified for some reason, in which case I'll go on to the next user, and so forth. So, if somebody "beats you to the punch", but they already have >10k rep, go ahead and post your question! Who knows - you could well win the bounty.

These rules are subject to revision by me at any time and for any reason. (But I probably won't unless I seriously overlooked something important.)

### Studio Ghibli anime that don't have tags

- [castle-in-the-sky](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle-in-the-sky) - [ask a question about **Castle in the Sky**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=castle-in-the-sky)
- [grave-of-the-fireflies](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grave-of-the-fireflies) - [ask a question about **Grave of the Fireflies**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=grave-of-the-fireflies)
- [only-yesterday](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/only-yesterday) - [ask a question about **Only Yesterday** (Omoide Poro Poro)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=only-yesterday)
- [pom-poko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pom-poko) - [ask a question about **Pom Poko**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=pom-poko)
- [whisper-of-the-heart](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/whisper-of-the-heart) - [ask a question about **Whisper of the Heart**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=whisper-of-the-heart)
- [mononoke-hime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mononoke-hime) - [ask a question about **Mononoke Hime**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=mononoke-hime)
- [my-neighbors-the-yamadas](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/my-neighbors-the-yamadas) - [ask a question about **My Neighbors the Yamadas**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=my-neighbors-the-yamadas)
- [the-cat-returns](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-cat-returns) - [ask a question about **The Cat Returns**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=the-cat-returns)
- [tales-from-earthsea](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-from-earthsea) - [ask a question about **Tales from Earthsea**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tales-from-earthsea)
- [arrietty](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrietty) - [ask a question about **Karigurashi no Arrietty** (The Secret World of Arrietty)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=arrietty)
- [from-up-on-poppy-hill](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-up-on-poppy-hill) - [ask a question about **From Up On Poppy Hill** (Kokurikozaka Kara)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=from-up-on-poppy-hill)
- [princess-kaguya](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/princess-kaguya) - [ask a question about **The Tale of the Princess Kaguya**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=princess-kaguya)
- [when-marnie-was-there](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/when-marnie-was-there) - [ask a question about **When Marnie was There** (Omoide no Marnie)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=when-marnie-was-there)
- [ocean-waves](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocean-waves) - [ask a question about **Ocean Waves** (I Can Hear the Sea / Umi ga Kikoeru)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ocean-waves)
- [ronia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronia) - [ask a question about **Ronia the Robber's Daughter** (Sanzoku no Musume Ronia)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ronia)

Additionally, if you want to make a tag for any other Ghibli thing I haven't listed above (e.g. short films), go right ahead, and I'll award you a bounty if you qualify. I just don't want to list all of them here, because there's a lot of them.

Comment: Just FYI, I had <10k when this was originally posted. I don't mind missing the bounty though, the question got me a good but of rep anyway

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Never fear - you'll still get a bounty!

Comment: hoo-ray :) \ o /

Answer (score 3):

Since March is over and all bounty-eligible questions have a score of +1 or better right now, this iteration of the bounties-for-tags program is over. The following tags were created:

- [castle-in-the-sky](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle-in-the-sky) - [Is Nadia voluntarily inspired by Castle in the Sky?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20229/)
- [pom-poko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pom-poko) - [Why do the racoons in pompoko have such large genitalia?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19936/)
- [mononoke-hime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mononoke-hime) - [Why didn't Ashitaka return to his village after his curse was lifted?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20042/)
- [tales-from-earthsea](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-from-earthsea) - [Why did Arren kill his father?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19767/)
- [from-up-on-poppy-hill](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-up-on-poppy-hill) - [What are the differences between Studio Ghibli's film adaptation and the original manga of "From Up On Poppy Hill"?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/20380/)
- [ronia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronia) - [What is the source material, if any, for Sanzoku no Musume Ronja?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/19768/)

I thought we had an Arrietty question at one point, but I'm not seeing it, so I guess I was hallucinating or something.

Anyway, this means that the following users win bounties from me:

- [Gao Weiwei](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8486/gao-weiwei) wins 100 reputation, for creating [tales-from-earthsea](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-from-earthsea) and [from-up-on-poppy-hill](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/from-up-on-poppy-hill).
- [Mindwin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2808/mindwin) wins 50 reputation, for creating [mononoke-hime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mononoke-hime).
- [neothoron](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8446/neothoron) wins 50 reputation, for creating [castle-in-the-sky](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/castle-in-the-sky).
- [Toshinou Kyouko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/toshinou-kyouko) wins 50 reputation, for creating [pom-poko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pom-poko).
- [Tsugumori-704](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/11206/tsugumori-704) wins 50 reputation, for creating [ronia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ronia).

Congratulations! I'll leave bounties for you folks up for about a day, and then award them to you. Since there are more than three of you this time, I'll have to do this in two batches.

Lastly - the [**April 2015** bounties-for-tags program](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2305/) is now open. The theme: sports anime.

Comment: I posted the Arrietty question, but I deleted it since it seemed pretty ignored and I wanted to clean up after myself a little, with all the unanswered questions I've posted.

Comment: So no need to fear for your mental health ;)