# April 2015 bounties for tags: sports anime, 2005-present

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

### The rules

If you create a tag for a **sports** anime (see the list below) that aired in 2005 or later, I will award you a <s>**50-reputation bounty**</s> **100-reputation bounty** (With help from Madara Uchiha), provided that:

- The question is posted during the month of **April 2015**.
- The question receives a net score of at least **+1** by May 7, 2015, and isn't closed or deleted. (We want good questions, not bad ones.)
- You have posted at least one answer on the site with a score of at least 0. (Bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions.)
- You have less than 15,000 reputation at the time of this posting. (This excludes Krazer / Jon Lin / Logan / Eric: users with 15k rep will have almost all privileges even after the site graduates.) <sub>This is a change from the March 2015 contest, where the cutoff was 10,000 reputation.</sub>

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 rep), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag), and somebody will come by and make a tag for you. I will give *you* (rather than the higher-rep user who physically creates the tag) credit for creating the tag.

There is no limit on the number of bounties you can win (other than that you obviously can't win more bounties than there are tags to be made).

### Sports anime from 2005-present that don't have tags

#### Baseball

- [ace-of-the-diamond](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ace-of-the-diamond) - [ask a question about **Ace of the Diamond** (Daiya no A)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ace-of-the-diamond)
- [cross-game](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-game) - [ask a question about **Cross Game**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cross-game)
- [major](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major) - [ask a question about **Major**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=major)
- [moshidora](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moshidora) - [ask a question about **Moshidora**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=moshidora)
- [ookiku-furikabutte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ookiku-furikabutte) - [ask a question about **Ookiku Furikabutte** (Big Roundup)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ookiku-furikabutte)
- [play-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play-ball) - [ask a question about **Play Ball**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=play-ball)
- [taisho-baseball-girls](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taisho-baseball-girls) - [ask a question about **Taisho Baseball Girls**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=taisho-baseball-girls)

#### Combat sports other than wrestling

- [bamboo-blade](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bamboo-blade) - [ask a question about **Bamboo Blade**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=bamboo-blade) (kendo)
- [ben-to](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ben-to) - [ask a question about **Ben-To**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ben-to) (martial shopping)
- [ring-ni-kakero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ring-ni-kakero) - [ask a question about **Ring ni Kakero**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ring-ni-kakero) (boxing)
- [walkure-romanze](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walkure-romanze) - [ask a question about **Walkure Romanze**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=walkure-romanze) (jousting)

#### Cycling

- [idaten-jump](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idaten-jump) - [ask a question about **Idaten Jump**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=idaten-jump)
- [nasu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nasu) - [ask a question about **Nasu** (Summer in Andalusia / Suitcase no Wataridori)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nasu)

#### Soccer (i.e. non-American football)

- [giant-killing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/giant-killing) - [ask a question about **Giant Killing**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=giant-killing)
- [ginga-e-kickoff](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-e-kickoff) - [ask a question about **Ginga e Kickoff**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ginga-e-kickoff)
- [golden-kids](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/golden-kids) - [ask a question about **Golden Kids**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=golden-kids)
- [the-knight-in-the-area](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-knight-in-the-area) - [ask a question about **Knight in the Area** (Area no Kishi)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=the-knight-in-the-area)

#### Tennis

- [baby-steps](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baby-steps) - [ask a question about **Baby Steps**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=baby-steps)
- [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu) - [ask a question about **Teekyuu**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=teekyuu)
- [softenni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/softenni) - [ask a question about **Softenni**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=softenni)

#### Volleyball

- [attacker-you](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/attacker-you) - [ask a question about **Attacker You!**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=attacker-you)
- [shoujo-fight](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shoujo-fight) - [ask a question about **Shoujo Fight**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=shoujo-fight)

#### Vehicle racing

- [capeta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/capeta) - [ask a question about **Capeta**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=capeta)
- [immortal-grand-prix](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/immortal-grand-prix) - [ask a question about **Immortal Grand Prix** (IGPX)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=immortal-grand-prix)
- [master-of-torque](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-of-torque) - [ask a question about **Master of Torque**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=master-of-torque)
- [oban-star-racers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oban-star-racers) - [ask a question about **Oban Star Racers**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=oban-star-racers)
- [redline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redline) - [ask a question about **Redline**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=redline)
- [tailenders](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tailenders) - [ask a question about **Tailenders**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tailenders)
- [wangan-midnight](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wangan-midnight) - [ask a question about **Wangan Midnight**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=wangan-midnight)

#### Wrestling

- [matsutarou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matsutarou) - [ask a question about **Abarenbou Rikishi!! Matsutarou**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=matsutarou)
- [kakutou-bijin-wulong](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kakutou-bijin-wulong) - [ask a question about **Kakutou Bijin Wulong** (Fighting Beauty Wulong)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kakutou-bijin-wulong)
- [kick-heart](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kick-heart) - [ask a question about **Kick-Heart**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kick-heart)
- [sekatsuyo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekatsuyo) - [ask a question about **Sekai de Ichiban Tsuyoku Naritai!** (Wanna be the Strongest in the World)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sekatsuyo)

#### Other

- [buzzer-beater](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buzzer-beater) - [ask a question about **Buzzer Beater**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=buzzer-beater) (basketball)
- [mudazumo-naki-kaikaku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mudazumo-naki-kaikaku) - [ask a question about **Mudazumo Naki Kaikaku** (The Legend of Koizumi)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=mudazumo-naki-kaikaku) (glorious [Super Aryan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwTI6.png) mahjong) (If you create this tag, you get a +100 bounty instead of a +50 bounty.)
- [nana-maru-san-batsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nana-maru-san-batsu) - [ask a question about **Nana Maru San Batsu**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nana-maru-san-batsu) (competitive quizzing) (Yes I know this isn't an anime and only dubiously even a sport, but this is my contest and I make the rules so neener neener. If you create this tag, you get a +150 bounty instead of a +50 bounty.)
- [phi-brain](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phi-brain) - [ask a question about **Phi Brain**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=phi-brain) (puzzling)
- [ping-pong](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping-pong) - [ask a question about **Ping Pong**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ping-pong) (take a guess)
- [shion-no-ou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shion-no-ou) - [ask a question about **Shion no Ou**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=shion-no-ou) (shogi)
- [skating-ring-kaleidoscope](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skating-ring-kaleidoscope) - [ask a question about **Skating Ring Kaleidoscope** (Ginban Kaleidoscope)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=skating-ring-kaleidoscope) (ice skating)
- [suzuka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/suzuka) - [ask a question about **Suzuka**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=suzuka) (track and field)
- [tsuritama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsuritama) - [ask a question about **Tsuritama**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tsuritama) (fishing)
- [yama-no-susume](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yama-no-susume) - [ask a question about **Yama no Susume** (Encouragement of Climb)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=yama-no-susume) (mountain climbing)

This list is substantially derived from [this AniDB search](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?type.web=1&type.unknown=1&type.tvspecial=1&type.tvseries=1&type.ova=1&type.other=1&type.musicvideo=1&type.movie=1&tag.2881=300&show=animelist&orderby.name=0.1&noalias=1&do.update=update&airdate1=2015-03-31&airdate0=2005-01-01) and similar searches for the sub-tags underneath themes::sports, with some after-the-fact curation because AniDB has dubious tagging in some places.

I'm sure this list isn't exhaustive. If you want bounty credit for a sports anime from 2005 onwards that I haven't listed here, just leave a comment on this post and I'll have a look at it. I am willing to be fairly open with regard to what counts as a "sports" anime.

Comment: Bounty rewards for March 2015 bounties-for-tags will happen in a day or two.

Comment: There is a basquash question on the site already - http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3658/is-there-a-difference-between-bfb-and-basquash

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Right you are. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: is puzzle solving counted as sport?

Comment: @Ezui Do you have a particular anime/manga/whatever in mind?

Comment: how about Phi-Brain?

Comment: @Ezui Sure, that's sport-y enough for me.

Comment: @senshin I have one question that's on track for the tumbleweed badge :P if you could just ignore that question~~

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko lol okay

Comment: nooooo, it was upvoteeedd

Comment: Summary/awards post and next month's post to come tomorrow, most likely.

Comment: I forgot the - in kick-heart

Comment: @ToshinouKyouko Noted; I'll toss you another 50-rep bounty later on.

Answer (score 5):

April is over in all time zones, and all relevant questions have a score of at least +1. Here are the awards for the month:

- [ginga-e-kickoff](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-e-kickoff) - [Does Reika return later in the series?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21273/)
- [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu) - [How much of Teekyuu is actually about Tennis or the Tennis club?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20800/)
- [redline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redline) - [Is there any reason why the race takes place on Roboworld?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20637/)
- [matsutarou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matsutarou) - [Is Matsutarou imitating a famous Japanese enka singer?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21175/)
- [mudazumo-naki-kaikaku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mudazumo-naki-kaikaku) - [Is it physically possible to turn a mahjong tile white with a super grip?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20522/)
- [phi-brain](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phi-brain) - [How did Gammon solve the puzzle in episode 2?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21221/)
- [ping-pong](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping-pong) - [What does it mean to be a poster child of type B blood?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20607/)
- [tsuritama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsuritama) - [What are these people doing in front of a shrine?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20943/)
- [yama-no-susume](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yama-no-susume) - [Is Fuji-san really that easy to be climbed?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21098/)
- [kick-heart](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kick-heart) - [Did KickHeart reveal a breakdown of its expenses?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/20912/)

This means that the following users win bounties (plus matching from Madara at his discretion):

- [Frosteeze](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/293/) wins 100 rep for [ginga-e-kickoff](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ginga-e-kickoff) and [ping-pong](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping-pong)
- [Oshino Shinobu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869/) wins 50 rep for [redline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/redline)
- [Toshinou Kyouko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1530/) wins 100 rep (and loses a potential Tumbleweed badge) for [matsutarou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matsutarou) and [kick-heart](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kick-heart)
- [Sp300](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/13542/) wins 100 rep for [mudazumo-naki-kaikaku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mudazumo-naki-kaikaku)
- [Ezui](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8802/) wins 50 rep for [phi-brain](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phi-brain)
- [Maroon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2604/) wins 50 rep for [tsuritama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsuritama)
- [Jan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/13532/) wins 50 rep for [yama-no-susume](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yama-no-susume)

Thanks to all users for participating; I'll award the bounties in three batches. Also, many thanks to Jon Lin for creating [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu), but he's above the rep cutoff, so he doesn't win a bounty.

[Next month's post is up](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/). The theme: visual novels (and anime adaptations thereof).