# May 2015 bounties for tags: visual novels and adaptations thereof

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

## The rules

If you create a tag for a visual novel (or an anime adaptation thereof), I will award you a **50-reputation bounty**, provided that:

- The question is posted during the month of **May 2015**.
- The question receives a net score of at least **+1** by June 7, 2015, and isn't closed or deleted. (We want good questions, not bad ones.)
- You have posted at least one answer on the site with a score of at least 0. (Bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions.)
- You have less than 20,000 reputation at the time of this posting. (This excludes Krazer / Jon Lin. Users with 20,000 reputation will have all privileges after graduation, and don't really need any more rep.) <sub>This is a change from the April 2015 contest, where the cutoff was 15,000 reputation.</sub>

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 rep), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag), and somebody will come by and make a tag for you. I will give *you* (rather than the higher-rep user who physically creates the tag) credit for creating the tag.

In the interest of getting broader participation, I will award at most 4 bounties (so, 200 reputation) to any one user. <sub>This is a change from the April 2015 contest.</sub>

## Eligible tags

Below, I list a number of popular visual novels (and anime adaptations thereof) that don't have tags yet. However, **any** visual novel that doesn't have a tag is eligible to win a bounty, as long as you leave a comment here mentioning it. The list below is mostly provided to suggest some things you might want to read/watch if you don't have any particular questions in mind.

### [Some VNs without anime adaptations](https://vndb.org/v/all?q=;fil=hasani-0.tagspoil-0;o=d;s=pop)

- [cross-channel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-channel) - [ask a question about **Cross Channel**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cross-channel) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v66))</sub>
- [ever17](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ever17) - [ask a question about **Ever17 -The Out of Infinity-**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=ever17) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v17))</sub>
- [heartful-boyfriend](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heartful-boyfriend) - [ask a question about **Heartful Boyfriend** (Hatoful Kareshi, a.k.a. "the pigeon VN")](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=heartful-boyfriend) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v7836))</sub>
- [hoshizora-no-memoria](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoshizora-no-memoria) - [ask a question about **Hoshizora no Memoria**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=hoshizora-no-memoria) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1474))</sub>
- [kara-no-shoujo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kara-no-shoujo) - [ask a question about **Kara no Shoujo**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kara-no-shoujo) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v810))</sub>
- [katawa-shoujo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/katawa-shoujo) - [ask a question about **Katawa Shoujo**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=katawa-shoujo) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v945))</sub>
- [kira-kira](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kira-kira) - [ask a question about **Kira Kira**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kira-kira) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v414))</sub>
- [monmusu-quest](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monmusu-quest) - [ask a question about **Monmusu Quest** (Monster Girl Quest)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=monmusu-quest) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v810))</sub>
- [narcissu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/narcissu) - [ask a question about **Narcissu**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=narcissu) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v10))</sub>
- [planetarian](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetarian) - [ask a question about **Planetarian**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=planetarian) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v34))</sub>
- [phoenix-wright](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phoenix-wright) - [ask a question about **Phoenix Wright: Ace Attorney** (Gyakuten Saiban)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=phoenix-wright) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v711))</sub>
- [rewrite](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite) - [ask a question about **Rewrite**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=rewrite) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v751))</sub>
- [saya-no-uta](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saya-no-uta) - [ask a question about **Saya no Uta**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=saya-no-uta) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v97))</sub>
- [sengoku-rance](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sengoku-rance) - [ask a question about **Sengoku Rance**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sengoku-rance) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v487))</sub>
- [sharin-no-kuni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharin-no-kuni) - [ask a question about **Sharin no Kuni, Himawari no Shoujo**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sharin-no-kuni) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v57))</sub>
- [wanko-to-kurasou](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wanko-to-kurasou) - [ask a question about **Wanko to Kurasou**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=wanko-to-kurasou) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v812))</sub>
- [yume-miru-kusuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yume-miru-kusuri) - [ask a question about **Yume Miru Kusuri**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=yume-miru-kusuri) <sub>([VNDB](https://vndb.org/v44))</sub>

### [Some VNs with anime adaptations](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?type.web=1&type.unknown=1&type.tvspecial=1&type.tvseries=1&type.ova=1&type.other=1&type.musicvideo=1&type.movie=1&tagid=2804&show=tag&reltb=animetb&orderby.name=0.1&noalias=1&cat.minweight=0&page=0)

- [11eyes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/11eyes) - [ask a question about **11eyes**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=11eyes) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6682/11eyes), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v729))</sub>
- [akane-iro-ni-somaru-saka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/akane-iro-ni-somaru-saka) - [ask a question about **Akane-iro ni Somaru Saka**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=akane-iro-ni-somaru-saka) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/4744/Akane-iro_ni_Somaru_Saka), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v547))</sub>
- [baldr-force](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/baldr-force) - [ask a question about **Baldr Force**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=baldr-force) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1682/Baldr_Force_Exe_Resolution), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v221))</sub>
- [canaan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canaan) - [ask a question about **Canaan** (428: Fuusa sareta Shibuya de)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=canaan) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5356/Canaan), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1299))</sub>
- [canvas](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/canvas) - [ask a question about **Canvas**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=canvas) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/695/Canvas:_Sepia-iro_no_Motif), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v175))</sub>
- [comic-party](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comic-party) - [ask a question about **Comic Party**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=comic-party) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/289/Comic_Party), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v177))</sub>
- [daitoshokan-no-hitsujikai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/daitoshokan-no-hitsujikai) - [ask a question about **Daitoshokan no Hitsujikai** (A Good Librarian Like a Good Shepherd)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=daitoshokan-no-hitsujikai) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/17827/Daitoshokan_no_Hitsujikai), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v8158))</sub>
- [final-approach](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-approach) - [ask a question about **Final Approach** (Phi-naru Approach)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=final-approach) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/119/Final_Approach), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v755))</sub>
- [fortune-arterial](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fortune-arterial) - [ask a question about **Fortune Arterial**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=fortune-arterial) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8536/Fortune_Arterial:_Akai_Yakusoku), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v87))</sub>
- [gift](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gift) - [ask a question about **Gift: Eternal Rainbow**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=gift) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1581/Gift:_Eternal_Rainbow), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v440))</sub>
- [meine-liebe](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meine-liebe) - [ask a question about **Gin'yuu Mokushiroku Meine Liebe**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=meine-liebe) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/336/Ginyuu_Mokushiroku_Meine_Liebe), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v3996))</sub>
- [green-green](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-green) - [ask a question about **Green Green**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=green-green) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/133/Green_Green), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v178))</sub>
- [happiness](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/happiness) - [ask a question about **Happiness!**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=happiness) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1570/Happiness!), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v362))</sub>
- [harukanaru-toki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harukanaru-toki) - [ask a question about **Harukanaru Toki no Naka de** (Within the Expanse of a Distant Time)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=harukanaru-toki) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/247/Harukanaru_Toki_no_Naka_de:_Hachiyou_Shou), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1794))</sub>
- [heart-no-kuni-no-alice](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heart-no-kuni-no-alice) - [ask a question about **Heart no Kuni no Alice** (Alice in the Country of Hearts)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=heart-no-kuni-no-alice) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/4713/Heart_no_Kuni_no_Alice:_Wonderful_Wonder_World), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v801))</sub>
- [hiiro-no-kakera](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiiro-no-kakera) - [ask a question about **Hiiro no Kakera** (Scarlet Fragment)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=hiiro-no-kakera) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/12461/Hiiro_no_Kakera), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1629))</sub>
- [kamigami-no-asobi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kamigami-no-asobi) - [ask a question about **Kamigami no Asobi**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kamigami-no-asobi) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/21563/Kamigami_no_Asobi), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v10273))</sub>
- [kimi-ga-nozomu-eien](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kimi-ga-nozomu-eien) - [ask a question about **Kimi ga Nozomu Eien**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kimi-ga-nozomu-eien) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/147/Kimi_ga_Nozomu_Eien), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v94))</sub>
- [kimikiss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kimikiss) - [ask a question about **Kimikiss**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kimikiss) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2927/Kimikiss_Pure_Rouge), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1187))</sub>
- [kiniro-no-corda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiniro-no-corda) - [ask a question about **Kin'iro no Corda**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=kiniro-no-corda) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/20971/Kiniro_no_Corda:_Blue%E2%99%AASky), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1014))</sub>
- [demonbane](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/demonbane) - [ask a question about **Demonbane**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=demonbane) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1067/Kishin_Houkou_Demonbane_(2006)), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v231))</sub>
- [koichoco](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koichoco) - [ask a question about **Koi to Senkyo to Chocolate**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=koichoco) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/12175/Koi_to_Senkyo_to_Chocolate), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v4028))</sub>
- [memories-off](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memories-off) - [ask a question about **Memories Off**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=memories-off) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/361/Memories_Off), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1152))</sub>
- [myself-yourself](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/myself-yourself) - [ask a question about **Myself; Yourself**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=myself-yourself) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2926/Myself_;_Yourself), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1151))</sub>
- [nanatsuiro-drops](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanatsuiro-drops) - [ask a question about **Nanatsuiro Drops**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=nanatsuiro-drops) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1688/Nanatsuiro%E2%98%85Drops), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v193))</sub>
- [oretsuba](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oretsuba) - [ask a question about **Oretachi ni Tsubasa wa Nai** (We Without Wings)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=oretsuba) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/9922/Oretachi_ni_Tsubasa_wa_Nai:_Under_the_Innocent_Sky.), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1141))</sub>
- [otoboku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/otoboku) - [ask a question about **Otome wa Boku ni Koishiteru**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=otoboku) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1569/Otome_wa_Boku_ni_Koishiteru), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v195))</sub>
- [princess-lover](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/princess-lover) - [ask a question about **Princess Lover!**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=princess-lover) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6201/Princess_Lover!), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v765))</sub>
- [prism-ark](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prism-ark) - [ask a question about **Prism Ark**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=prism-ark) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1807/Prism_Ark), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v200))</sub>
- [sakura-taisen](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakura-taisen) - [ask a question about **Sakura Taisen**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=sakura-taisen) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/561/Sakura_Taisen), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v952))</sub>
- [polyphonica](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polyphonica) - [ask a question about **Shinkyoku Soukai Polyphonica**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=polyphonica) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1727/Shinkyoku_Soukai_Polyphonica), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v228))</sub>
- [shuffle](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shuffle) - [ask a question about **Shuffle!**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=shuffle) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/79/Shuffle!), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v28))</sub>
- [shukufuku-no-campanella](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shukufuku-no-campanella) - [ask a question about **Shukufuku no Campanella**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=shukufuku-no-campanella) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6979/Shukufuku_no_Campanella), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v1337))</sub>
- [tayutama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tayutama) - [ask a question about **Tayutama**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tayutama) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/5734/Tayutama:_Kiss_on_My_Deity), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v828))</sub>
- [they-are-my-noble-masters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/they-are-my-noble-masters) - [ask a question about **They Are My Noble Masters** (Kimi ga Aruji de Shitsuji ga Ore de)](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=they-are-my-noble-masters) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/3229/Kimi_ga_Aruji_de_Shitsuji_ga_Ore_de), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v581))</sub>
- [togainu-no-chi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/togainu-no-chi) - [ask a question about **Togainu no Chi**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=togainu-no-chi) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8449/Togainu_no_Chi), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v434))</sub>
- [to-heart](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-heart) - [ask a question about **To Heart**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=to-heart) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/472/To_Heart), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v18))</sub>
- [tokimeki-memorial](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokimeki-memorial) - [ask a question about **Tokimeki Memorial**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tokimeki-memorial) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1555/Tokimeki_Memorial:_Only_Love), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v19))</sub>
- [true-tears](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/true-tears) - [ask a question about **True Tears**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=true-tears) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/2129/True_Tears), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v79))</sub>
- [tsuyokiss](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tsuyokiss) - [ask a question about **Tsuyokiss**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=tsuyokiss) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1198/Tsuyokiss), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v397))</sub>
- [uta-no-prince-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uta-no-prince-sama) - [ask a question about **Uta no Prince-sama**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=uta-no-prince-sama) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/10321/Uta_no%E2%98%86Prince-sama%E2%99%AA_Maji_Love_1000), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v4602))</sub>
- [walkure-romanze](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/walkure-romanze) - [ask a question about **Walkure Romanze**](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=walkure-romanze) <sub>([MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/19151/Walkure_Romanze), [VNDB](https://vndb.org/v4041))</sub>

Comment: How broad of a definition of visual novel are you using? There are at least few games on your list that wouldn't generally be considered visual novels in Japan.

Comment: @RossRidge You're right; Phoenix Wright certainly comes to mind as an example of that. Basically, I went down [a list on AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?type.web=1&type.unknown=1&type.tvspecial=1&type.tvseries=1&type.ova=1&type.other=1&type.musicvideo=1&type.movie=1&tagid=2804&show=tag&reltb=animetb&orderby.name=0.1&noalias=1&cat.minweight=0&page=0) and [a list on VNDB](https://vndb.org/v/all?q=;fil=hasani-0.tagspoil-0;o=d;s=pop) and copied stuff over from those lists. I guess "anything listed on VNDB" is a good operational definition for "visual novel" here?

Comment: Good as definition as any I guess.

Comment: The English translations of Hatoful Kareshi keep the pun, so I think [Hatoful Boyfriend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatoful_Boyfriend) might be better

Comment: [tag:akibastrip] has VN sections and is labelled as a VN on Steam - I don't know if it is though, it's half beat-em-up anyway

Comment: Am somewhat busy at the moment; will award bounties in a day or two.

Comment: Should we be looking for June tag bounties anytime soon?

Answer (score 5):

Bounties on four questions from two users for May have been awarded.

[Frosteeze](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/293/frosteeze): [two](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21300/63) [tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21925/63). +100 rep.

[Torisuda](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/7579/torisuda): [two](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21311/63) [tags](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/21498/63). +100 rep.

Please leave a comment if you have submitted a question that fulfills the above mentioned criteria, but have not been awarded a bounty or have not been awarded the correct amount.

Comment: Aw, crud. Sorry, this completely slipped my mind. Thank you for stepping up and awarding these bounties!