# Monthly Tag Bounties

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

In the past, we had tag bounties before and I would like to bring them back. They draw attention to older anime and it might serve to increase user participation. This meta post will serve to gauge interest in a monthly tag bounty as a community feature and who wants to provide the rep points needed for the bounties.

The tag bounties that I have in mind, however, will not only focus attention on older anime, but also on currently running shows. I believe that this will attract newcomers and not just old-timers.

If we are to have regular tag bounties, I propose that it should follow the format we had in the past. Examples include:

- [April 2015 Tag Bounties](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2305/april-2015-bounties-for-tags-sports-anime-2005-present)
- [February 2015 Tag Bounties](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/february-2015-bounties-for-tags-summer-2011-shows)
- [May 2015 Tag Bounties](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2342/may-2015-bounties-for-tags-visual-novels-and-adaptations-thereof)

It would also need to loosely follow **Senshin's** original [proposal for Tag Bounties](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/proposal-bounties-for-tags).

In the past, he would be the one coordinating these events. Unfortunately, he has been busy lately and I think we as a community should pick up where he left off. That means that anyone should be able to coordinate these Tag Bounty events, should they choose to, with a maximum of one event per month. The theme should be [discussed in our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6697/maid-cafe-), with the mods having the final say in everything.

So, who would be interested in a monthly tag bounty event? Who wants to contribute the bounties in these events?

Comment: It's less that I've been busy and more that they just didn't seem all that effective to me. The particular way I was doing them (picking a theme or feature and then attempting to specify all the anime with that theme/feature) was also somewhat labor-intensive. I'll add that the reason that I focused mostly on older stuff was that the newer stuff tends to get asked about relatively organically, whereas older stuff just kind of doesn't.

Comment: For me, seasonal tag bounties aren't that satisfying to reward - Something that rewards/encourages good questions is more likely to make me give a bounty in general. So for me, I would give bounties to a 'qs you may have missed' style event - or some event with a particularly interesting theme. Just my 2 cents

Comment: (To be clear, the point of the tag bounties thing was to ensure that we have as many tags in the system as possible, thereby circumventing the problem of users coming to the site, trying to ask a question, finding no tag for their anime, and then leaving. I agree that awarding bounties for questions that are actually good in some sense is more satisfying, but it doesn't actually solve this particular problem.)