# September 2016 bounties for tags: literally almost anything

Tags: discussion, bounties-for-tags

## The rules

If you create a tag for any series, franchise, person, or organization, I will award you a **50-reputation bounty**, provided that:

- The question that creates the tag is posted during the month of **September 2016** (in any time zone).
- The question receives a net score of at least **+1** by October 7, 2016, and isn't closed or deleted.
- You have posted **at least one answer** on the site (to any question whatsoever) with a score of at least **0**. (Bounties can only be awarded to answers, not questions.)
- The tag is for a series, franchise, person, or organization. If you create a tag that is none of those, like [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production), you will not receive a bounty.
- You have less than 20,000 reputation at the time of this posting. (This excludes Krazer / Jon Lin / me / Toshinou Kyouko / Logan M. We all have enough reputation as is.)

If you do not have [enough reputation to create a tag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) (150 rep), that's fine - post the question anyway with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag), and somebody will come by and make a tag for you. I will give you (rather than the higher-rep user who physically creates the tag) the bounty.

There is no limit on how many bounties you can earn (unless you bankrupt me of reputation, in which case I guess it's first-come-first-serve).

---

Supplementary note: The previous batch of bounties-for-tags (Feb-May 2015) was less effective than I would have hoped. This might be because the bounties were conditional on the tags being in some prescribed category ([at the time, it seemed like a good idea to me](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2227/proposal-bounties-for-tags#comment3116_2227)). This time, I'm going for a mostly unconditional approach, in hopes that this will get people to ask more questions. This might work, or it might not. We'll see.

Comment: This is where following current season anime will pay off for me. Too bad I already asked questions about Amanchu and Sweetness and Lightning; time to go catch up on Orange and Ange Vierge.

Comment: Although I did manage to strech a question out of a non-current season anime back in one of the 2015 contests @Torisuda, so … ;)

Answer (score 5):

The following tags earn bounties:

- [sengoku-youko](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sengoku-youko), by [user1821961](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/25995/user1821961)
- [mezzo-dsa](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mezzo-dsa), by [Gao](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/8486/gao)
- [maria-holic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maria-holic), by [Memor-X](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1587/memor-x)
- [kochikame](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kochikame), by [Dragon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/23346/dragon)
- [major](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/major), by [Arcane](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/6368/arcane)
- [hitori-no-shita](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hitori-no-shita), by [Maroon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2604/maroon)
- [rewrite](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rewrite), by [Ayase Eri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/7866/ayase-eri)
- [tales-of-phantasia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tales-of-phantasia), by [Memor-X](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/1587/memor-x)
- [school-rumble](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/school-rumble), by [Darjeeling](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2869/darjeeling)

The following additional tags were created, but will not earn a bounty:

- [time-travel-shoujo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-travel-shoujo) (ineligible: created by me)
- [hoshi-hitomi-silhouette](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hoshi-hitomi-silhouette) (ineligible: created by me)
- [masou-gakuen](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/masou-gakuen), by [Dan Whaley](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/13647/dan-whaley) (no answers on which to award the bounty)
- [planetarian](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/planetarian) (ineligible: created by me)
- [thunderbolt-fantasy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thunderbolt-fantasy), by [Racheet](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/28405/racheet) (no answers on which to award the bounty)

Bounties headed your way shortly!