# Spring 2015 series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

As has become something of a tradition by now, this is a meta post for listing and counting tags for the various full-length anime series which are airing in Spring 2015 season.

Previous posts in the series:

- [Creating tags for Fall 2014 series](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/)
- [Winter 2015 series tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/)

**What series are airing in Spring 2015, and which have tags?**

Answer (score 6):

I'm still using [Anichart](http://anichart.net/spring) with English titles, with the same system as the previous post for ordering. Feel free to make improvements.

- **Assassination Classroom** [assassination-classroom](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassination-classroom)
- **Fafner Exodus** [fafner-exodus](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fafner-exodus)
- **Kuroko's Basketball 3** [kuroko-no-basket](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kuroko-no-basket)

---

- **Battle Spirits: Burning Soul** *no tag*
- **My Teen Romantic Comedy SNAFU Zoku** [oregairu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oregairu)
- **Re-Kan!** [re-kan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/re-kan)
- **Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha ViVid** [nanoha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nanoha)
- **Dungeon ni Deai o Motomeru no wa Machigatteiru Darou ka?** [danmachi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danmachi)
- **The Disappearance of Nagato Yuki-chan** [nagato-yuki-chan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nagato-yuki-chan)
- **Shokugeki no Souma** [shokugeki-no-soma](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shokugeki-no-soma)
- **PriPara 2** *no tag*
- **Denpa Kyoushi** *no tag*
- **Kyoukai no Rinne** [kyoukai-no-rinne](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyoukai-no-rinne)
- **Seraph of the End** [owari-no-seraph](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owari-no-seraph)
- **High School DxD BorN** [high-school-dxd](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/high-school-dxd)
- **Gunslinger Stratos: The Animation** *no tag*
- **Fate/stay night: Unlimited Blade Works 2nd Season** [fate-stay-night](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-stay-night)
- **Plastic Memories** [plastic-memories](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plastic-memories)
- **Uta no☆Prince-sama♪ Maji Love Revolutions** *no tag*
- **Blood Blockade Battlefront** [kekkai-sensen](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kekkai-sensen)
- **Duel Masters VSR** *no tag*
- **The Heroic Legend of Arslan** *no tag*
- **Baby Steps 2** *no tag*
- **Show By Rock!!** *no tag*
- **Ghost in the Shell Arise: Alternative Architecture** [ghost-in-the-shell-arise](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghost-in-the-shell-arise)
- **Hello!! Kiniro Mosaic** [kiniro-mosaic](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kiniro-mosaic)
- **Ace of the Diamond: Second Season** *no tag*
- **JOKER 2** *no tag*
- **Mikagura Gakuen Kumikyoku** *no tag*
- **Hibike! Euphonium** [hibike-euphonium](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hibike-euphonium)
- **Gintama°** [gintama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gintama)
- **Ore Monogatari!!** *no tag*
- **Etotama** [etotama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etotama)
- **Houkago no Pleiades** [wish-upon-the-pleiades](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wish-upon-the-pleiades)
- **Triage X** *no tag*
- **Punch Line** [punchline](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punchline)
- **Nisekoi S2** [nisekoi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nisekoi)
- **Knights of Sidonia: Daikyuu Wakusei Seneki** [knights-of-sidonia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-of-sidonia)
- **Eikoku Ikke, Nihon o Taberu** *no tag*
- **Yamada-kun to Nananin no Majo** [yamada-and-the-7-witches](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yamada-and-the-7-witches)
- **Grisaia no Rakuen** [grisaia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grisaia)
- **Digimon Adventure tri.** [digimon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/digimon)
- **Lupin III (2015)** [lupin-the-third](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lupin-the-third)
- **Tesagure! Bukatsumono Spin-off Purupurun Charm to Asobou** [tesagure-bukatsumono](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tesagure-bukatsumono)

---

- **Danna ga Nani o Itteiru ka Wakaranai Ken - Second Thread** [danna-wakaranai-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/danna-wakaranai-ken)
- **Takamiya Nasuno Desu!** [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu)
- **Teekyuu 4** [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu)
- **Ameiro Cocoa** *no tag*
- **Narudoma** *no tag*
- **Urawa no Usagi-chan** *no tag*
- **Vampire Holmes** *no tag*
- **Robot Girls Z+** *no tag*

We currently have **32/52** tags.