# Fall 2015 series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

It's that time of the quarter again: the fall season of anime is starting. We want to get as many tags as possible for this season's shows into the system, both so we get more interesting content on the site and so that low-rep users don't have to bumble their way into the [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) workaround.

If you're looking for something to watch this season, consider picking something from the list below. Who knows, it might prompt you to ask some interesting questions!

(Previous editions: [summer 2015](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/), [spring 2015](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2303/), [and more](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags-by-season).)

Answer (score 7):

Note that shows for which we have tags are <s>struckthrough</s>. Additionally, shows for which we had tags *at the beginning of the season* are unbolded.

## New full-length shows

- **Brave Beats**
- <s>**Comet Lucifer**</s> [comet-lucifer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comet-lucifer)
- **Concrete Revolutio: Choujin Gensou**
- **Dance with Devils**
- <s>**Gakusen Toshi Asterisk**</s> [gakuen-toshi-asterisk](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gakuen-toshi-asterisk)
- <s>**Heavy Object**</s> [heavy-object](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heavy-object)
- **Kamisama Minarai: Himitsu no Cocotama** (use *himitsu-no-cocotama*)
- **Lance N' Masques**
- <s>One Punch Man</s> [one-punch-man](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-punch-man)
- **Ore ga Ojou-sama Gakkou ni "Shomin Sample" toshite Gets-sareta Ken** (use *shomin-sample*)
- <s>**Rakudai Kishi no Eiyuutan**</s> [rakudai-kishi-no-cavalry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rakudai-kishi-no-cavalry)
- <s>**Sakurako-san no Ashimoto ni wa Shitai ga Umatteiru**</s> [sakurako-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakurako-san)
- **Star Mu**, aka **High School Star Musical**
- <s>**Subete ga F ni Naru: The Perfect Insider**</s> [subete-ga-f-ni-naru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subete-ga-f-ni-naru)
- **Taimadou Gakuen 35 Shiken Shoutai** (use *35-shoutai*)
- **Valkyrie Drive: Mermaid**

## Full-length sequels

- <s>Aikatsu</s> [aikatsu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aikatsu)
- <s>Cardfight!! Vanguard G: Gears Crisis-hen</s> [cardfight-vanguard](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cardfight-vanguard)
- <s>Garo: Guren no Tsuki</s> [garo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garo)
- <s>Gochuumon wa Usagi Desu ka??</s> [is-the-order-a-rabbit](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/is-the-order-a-rabbit)
- <s>Haikyuu!! 2</s> [haikyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyuu)
- **Hidan no Aria**
- <s>K: Return of Kings</s> [k-project](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/k-project)
- <s>Kidou Senshi Gundam: Tekketsu no Orphans</s> [gundam](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam) (or, if you prefer, create a new tag *gundam-g-tekketsu*)
- **Kindaichi Shounen no Jikenbo R 2** (use *kindaichi-shounen*)
- <s>Noragami Aragoto</s> [noragami](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/noragami)
- **Osomatsu-san**
- <s>Owari no Seraph: Nagoya Kessen-hen</s> [owari-no-seraph](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owari-no-seraph) (cour 2 of a split-cour)
- <s>Owarimonogatari</s> [monogatari-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monogatari-series)
- **Peeping Life TV: Season 1??**
- <s>Pokemon XY & Z</s> [pokemon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon)
- **Shin Atashin'chi**
- <s>Shingeki! Kyojin Chuugakkou</s> [shingeki-no-kyojin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shingeki-no-kyojin)
- **Shinmai Maou no Testament Burst**
- **Soukyuu no Fafner: Exodus 2**
- <s>Utawarerumono: Itsuwari no Kamen</s> [utawarerumono](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utawarerumono)
- <s>World Trigger: Isekai kara no Toubousha</s> [world-trigger](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-trigger)
- <s>Young Black Jack</s> [black-jack](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/black-jack)
- <s>Yuru Yuri San☆Hai</s> [yuru-yuri](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yuru-yuri)

## Shorts

- **Ameiro Cocoa: Rainy Color e Youkoso!**
- **Anitore! EX**
- <s>Diabolik Lovers More,Blood</s> [diabolik-lovers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diabolik-lovers)
- **Doushite mo Eto ni Hairitai**
- **Fushigi na Somera-chan**
- **Fuusen Inu Tinny 2nd Season**
- <s>**Hacka Doll: The Animation**</s> [hacka-doll](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hacka-doll)
- <s>Hokuto no Ken: Ichigo Aji</s> [hokuto-no-ken](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hokuto-no-ken)
- **Itoshi no Muco**
- **JK-Meshi**
- **Kagewani**
- **Ketsuekigata-kun! 3**
- **Komori-san wa Kotowarenai**
- <s>**Kowabon**</s> [kowabon](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kowabon)
- **Kyoufu! Zombie Neko**
- **Mini Vanguard 2**
- <s>Miss Monochrome: The Animation 3</s> [miss-monochrome](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miss-monochrome)
- **Neko no Dayan: Nihon e Iku**
- **Onsen no Yousei Hakone-chan**
- **Tantei Team KZ Jiken Note**
- <s>Teekyuu 6</s> [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu)

## Leftovers from previous seasons

- <s>Aquarion Logos</s> [aquarion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aquarion)
- <s>Lupin III: L'avventura Italiana</s> [lupin-the-third](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lupin-the-third)
- <s>Ushio to Tora</s> [ushio-to-tora](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ushio-to-tora)

(and probably some others I missed)

## Movies coming out on BD this season

- **Sarusuberi: Miss Hokusai**

---

Listings culled from [Anichart](http://anichart.net/fall), [Senpai.moe](http://www.senpai.moe/?season=fall2015&sort=premiere&mode=table), and [The Cart Driver](http://thecartdriver.com/fall-2015-anime-season-preview/).

Comment: Crunchyroll simply lists _Subete ga F ni Naru_ as _The Perfect Insider_, so perhaps that (or alternatively, the Japanese romanized title) should be added as a synonym should any questions on the show come up.

Answer (score 2):

Please keep this answer voted below [the other one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2635/), so the other one is more visible.

I would like to set some targets for which tags we should try to have in the system by the time the season ends (at the end of December). Getting *all* of the currently unasked-about series in the system obviously isn't going to happen, since a lot of those series are e.g. family-oriented shows that nobody outside Japan watches.

Instead, I propose that we should try to focus on shows that are likely to have a reasonably-sized English-speaking viewer base. In my estimation, that means the following shows (that don't already have tags; bold for particularly "important" ones):

- <s>Comet Lucifer</s>
- Concrete Revolutio
- Dance with Devils
- <s>Gakusen Toshi Asterisk</s>
- <s>Hacka Doll</s> (a short, but by Trigger)
- <s>**Heavy Object**</s> (going to be super-popular because Kamachi)
- Hidan no Aria (this somehow got a sequel, so clearly somebody is still into the KugiRie-as-tsundere genre)
- <s>Rakudai Kishi no Eiyuutan</s>
- <s>Sakurako-san</s>
- Shinmai Maou no Testament
- Shomin Sample
- <s>**Subete ga F ni Naru**</s> (lots of hype here)
- Taimadou Gakuen 35 etc

I will probably watch most of these and ask questions about them as I have them. If you're watching any of these shows, you might like to try to do the same.

---

In summary: by the end of the fall 2015 season (plus a few days), we managed to get questions about 7/13 of the shows listed above. Not bad, though I have to think we could've done better. (I, personally, also watched Dance with Devils, but was unable to muster any interesting questions about it.)

Oh, well. On to winter 2016!