# Winter 2016 series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

The winter 2016 anime season is under way. We want to get as many tags as possible for this season's shows into the system, both so we get more interesting content on the site and so that low-rep users don't have to bumble their way into the [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) workaround.

If you're looking for something to watch, consider picking something from the list below. Who knows, it might prompt you to ask some interesting questions!

(Previous editions: [fall 2015](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2634/), [summer 2015](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/), and [more](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags-by-season).)

Answer (score 5):

Shows for which we have tags are <s>struckthrough</s>. Additionally, shows for which we had tags *at the beginning of the season* are unbolded.

## New full-length and half-length shows

- **Active Raid**
- <s>Ajin</s> [ajin-demi-human](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ajin-demi-human)
- **Ao no Kanata no Four Rhythm** (use `ao-no-kanata`)
- <s>Boku dake ga Inai Machi</s> [erased](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/erased)
- **Bubuki Buranki**
- <s>**Dagashi Kashi**</s> [dagashi-kashi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dagashi-kashi)
- <s>Dimension W</s> [dimension-w](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dimension-w)
- **Divine Gate**
- <s>Hai to Gensou no Grimgar</s> [grimgar](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grimgar)
- **Haruchika**
- <s>**Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo**</s> [konosuba](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba)
- <s>Koukaku no Pandora</s> [koukaku-no-pandora](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koukaku-no-pandora)
- <s>Koyomimonogatari</s> [monogatari-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monogatari-series) (half-length)
- **Luck & Logic**
- **Mahou Tsukai Precure**
- <s>Musaigen no Phantom World</s> [musaigen-no-phantom-world](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/musaigen-no-phantom-world)
- **Norn9**
- **Nurse Witch Komugi-chan R**
- **Phantasy Star Online 2: The Animation** (use `phantasy-star-online-2`)
- **Prince of Stride: Alternative** (use `prince-of-stride`)
- **Reikenzan: Hoshikuzu-tachi no Utage** (use `reikenzan`)
- **Saijaku Muhai no Bahamut**
- **Shoujo-tachi wa Kouya wo Mezasu** (use `shokomeza` and add `shoujotachi-wa-kouya` as a synonym)
- **Showa Genroku Rakugo Shinjuu** (use `rakugo-shinjuu`)

## Full-length sequels and spinoffs

- **Akagami no Shirayuki-hime** (cour 2 of split-cour)
- <s>Assassination Classroom 2</s> [assassination-classroom](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/assassination-classroom)
- <s>Durarara!!×2 Ketsu</s> [durarara](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/durarara) (cour 3 of split-cour)
- <s>Fairy Tail Zero</s> [fairy-tail-zero](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fairy-tail-zero)
- <s>Gate: Jieitai Kanochi nite Kaku Tatakaeri</s> [gate](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gate) (cour 2 of split-cour)
- **Schwarzesmarken** (I don't know whether we should use [muv-luv](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muv-luv) for this or not)

## Movies available outside Japan this cour

- **Glass no Hana to Kowasu Sekai** (use `garakowa` and add `glass-no-hana` as a synonym, or vice versa)
- <s>Kizumonogatari</s> [monogatari-series](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monogatari-series) (hype!)
- (probably others I'm missing)

## Shorts

- **Ketsuekigata-kun 4**
- **Kono Danshi, Mahou ga Oshigoto desu**
- **Mahou Shoujo nante mou Ii desu kara**
- **Mim Mam Mint**
- **Nijiiro Days**
- **Ojisan to Marshmallow**
- <s>Ooya-san wa Shishunki!</s> [ooyasan-wa-shishunki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ooyasan-wa-shishunki)
- **Oshiete! Gyaruko-chan**
- <s>**Sekkou Boys**</s> [sekko-boys](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sekko-boys)
- **She and Her Cat** (yes, as in the Makoto Shinkai one)
- **Sushi Police**
- **Tabimachi Late Show**
- <s>Teekyuu 7</s> [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu)
- <s>Yami Shibai 3</s> [yami-shibai](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yami-shibai)

## Leftovers from previous seasons

- <s>Garo: Guren no Tsuki</s> [garo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/garo)
- <s>Haikyuu!! 2</s> [haikyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haikyuu)
- <s>Heavy Object</s> [heavy-object](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/heavy-object)
- **Gundam: Tekketsu no Orphans** (or should this be subsumed under [gundam](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gundam)?)
- <s>Osomatsu-san</s> [osomatsu-san](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osomatsu-san)
- <s>Utawarerumono: Itsuwari no Kamen</s> [utawarerumono](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utawarerumono)

Listings culled from [Anichart](http://anichart.net/winter-16), [Senpai.moe](http://www.senpai.moe/?season=winter2016&sort=premiere&mode=table), and [The Cart Driver](http://thecartdriver.com/winter-2016-anime-season-preview/). I left out some stuff that pretty much nobody over here is going to watch, like "Ganbare! Lulu Lolo 3", whatever that is.

Comment: If we're going with the SFF-inspired tagging approach I suggested [here](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/2700/7579) for tagging separate continuities within a franchise, we need a separate tag for Tekketsu no Orphans, and questions on it should be tagged both "gundam" and "tekketsu-no-orphans" unless they also pertain to the entire Gundam franchise.

Comment: There's also [Koyomimonogatari](http://myanimelist.net/anime/32268/Koyomimonogatari) shorts! (No problem with the tag though, there's always [tag:monogatari-series])