# Summer 2015 series tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tags-by-season

Continuing on the tradition, let us tag as many series as possible, so that new users can find the tags easily without having to dabble with [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) workaround.

For  people new to this, [check out the rationale here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/).

Previous posts in the series:

- [Fall 2014 series tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1126/)
- [Winter 2015 series tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/)
- [Spring 2015 series tags](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2303/)

**What series are airing in Summer 2015, and which have tags?**

Comment: Why dont you just make it a wiki answer?

Comment: @PeterRaeves I will keep that in mind next time. I just followed the previous example, so I didn't make it a wiki. It will be turned into wiki shortly

Answer (score 8):

I use the names from [neregate](http://static.neregate.com/2015/05/neregate.com-Summer-2015-Anime-Chart-v2.jpg), adding a few missing series from [anichart](http://anichart.net/summer). Feel free to make improvements and update the post as it goes.

### Leftover from Spring season

- **Arslan Senki** [arslan-senki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arslan-senki)
- **Baby Steps 2**
- **Denpa Kyoushi** [denpa-kyoushi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denpa-kyoushi)
- **Eikoku Ikke, Nihon o Taberu**
- **Kyoukai no Rinne** [kyoukai-no-rinne](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kyoukai-no-rinne)
- **Nagato Yuki-chan no Shoushitsu** [nagato-yuki-chan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nagato-yuki-chan)
- **Ninja Slayer From Animation** [ninja-slayer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ninja-slayer)
- **Ore Monogatari!!**
- **Shoukugeki no Souma** [shokugeki-no-soma](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shokugeki-no-soma)

### Summer series

- **Akagami no Shirayuki-hime**
- **Aoharu x Kikanjuu**
- **Aquarion Logos**
- **Chaos Dragon: Sekiryuu Sen'eki**
- **Charlotte** [charlotte](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charlotte)
- **Chu Feng: BEE**
- **Classroom Crisis**
- **Dragon Ball Super** [dragon-ball](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball)
- **Durarara!! x2 Ten** [durarara](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/durarara)
- **Fate/kaleid liner Prisma Illya 2wei Herz!** [fate-kaleid-liner](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-kaleid-liner)
- **Gakkou Gurashi** [gakkou-gurashi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gakkou-gurashi)
- **Gangsta.**
- **Gatchaman Crowds insight** [gatchaman-crowds](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gatchaman-crowds)
- **Gate: Jietai Kanochi nite, Kaku Tatakaeri** [gate](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gate)
- **God Eater** [god-eater](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/god-eater)
- **Himouto! Umaru-chan** [himouto-umaru-chan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/himouto-umaru-chan)
- **Jitsu wa Watashi wa**
- **Joukamachi no Dandelion** [joukamachi-no-dandelion](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/joukamachi-no-dandelion)
- **Junjou Romantica 3**
- **Kangoku Gakuen**
- **Kuusen Madoshi Kouhosei no Kyoukan** [sky-wizards-academy](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sky-wizards-academy)
- **Monster Musume no Iru Nichijou** [monmusu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monmusu)
- **Non Non Biyori Repeat** [non-non-biyori](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-non-biyori)
- **Overlord** [overlord](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overlord)
- **Ranpo Kitan: Game of Laplace** [ranpo-kitan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ranpo-kitan)
- **Rokka no Yuusha** [rokka-no-yuusha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rokka-no-yuusha)
- **Senki Zesshou Symphogear GX** [senki-zesshou-symphogear](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senki-zesshou-symphogear)
- **Shimoneta to Iu Gainen ga Sonzai Shinai Taikutsu na Sekai** [shimoseka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shimoseka)
- **Sore ga Seiyuu!**
- **The IDOLM@STER Cinderella Girls Second Season** [the-idolmaster](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-idolmaster)
- **To Love-Ru -Trouble- Darkness 2nd** [to-love-ru](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/to-love-ru)
- **Ushio to Tora** [ushio-to-tora](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ushio-to-tora)
- **Venus Project**
- **Working!!!** [working](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/working)

### Shorts

- **Bikini Warriors**
- **Danchigai**
- **Hetalia: The World Twinkle**
- **Kaijuu Sakaba Kanpai!**
- **Kurayami Santa**
- **Makura no Danshi**
- **Million Doll**
- **Miss Monochrome Second Season** [miss-monochrome](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/miss-monochrome)
- **Okusama ga Seito Kaichou!**
- **Q Transformers: Kaettekita Convoy no Nazo 2**
- **Suzakinishi: The Animation**
- **Teekyuu 5** [teekyuu](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teekyuu)
- **Wakaba * Girl**
- **Wakako-Zake**
- **Wooser no Sono Higurashi Mugen-hen**

Comment: There are already tags for Gatchaman, but without following the series, I can't really tell which would be the correct one to specify here.